# Did Antifa distribute this pamphlet?

Tags: united-states, politics, racism

This is the pamphlet I'm talking about:

[image: image description below:]

> The evil white race must be destroyed!
>
> The white racist and their Heeb masters must be purged from the face of the earth!
>
> The children of the white racists are the future of the white race. This is where we must begin and end!
>
> With Trump in power it is far to late for conversion of the racist children.
>
> Thus we are left with only *one* option...
>   To do what must be done!!
>
> BUT take heart! After the purge we will live in a worker's paradise free from racism, sexism, homophobia, transphobia, and oppression!

I've seen it on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/rikvartigyan/status/898332432620937216).

Was a pamphlet like that one distributed by an Antifa group?

Here are some other links that make the claim:

- [FreedomOutpost](http://freedomoutpost.com/antifa-the-evil-white-race-must-be-destroyed/).
- [Protothema](http://en.protothema.gr/disturbing-antifa-pamphlet-calls-for-the-purge-of-white-race-photo/)

Comment: For others who may not be familiar, "heeb" is a derogatory shorthand/epitaph for "Hebrew."

Answer (score 75):

According to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/antifa-flyers-call-for-the-murder-of-white-children/), it is not real:

> This flyer was not created by antifa, nor was it distributed by the group in Charlottesville or anywhere else. [...]
>
> There are several reasons to be sure that these flyers are fake: the supposed antifa organization named on the flyers does not exist; the flyer does not use language espoused by antifa groups; and the images have been posted along with a wide variety of claims about antifa groups in various cities.

Snopes goes on expanding on these arguments and includes commentary by various antifa groups, all of which reject the message and antisemitism of the flyer. One of the groups concluded:

> This come across like what white supremacists tell each other about anti-fascists [...] It’s exactly like their fantasy/nightmare of white genocide and anti-whiteness that [they] think anyone who hates racism believes in.

Comment: While this answer is probably true, I would hesitate implicitly trusting Snopes's conclusions about anything. https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/is-snopes-a-valid-primary-source